# return value from completion handler is not updated in DispatchQueue.main.async block

Tags: swift, completionhandler, dispatch-queue

I am calling a function with completion handler from one class to another class

called class:

```
class PVClass
{

var avgMonthlyAcKw:Double = 0.0

var jsonString:String!

func estimateMonthlyACkW (areaSqFt:Float, completion: @escaping(Double) -> () ){

var capacityStr:String = ""

let estimatedCapacity = Float(areaSqFt/66.0)
capacityStr = String(format: "%.2f", estimatedCapacity)

// Build some Url string
var urlString:String = "https://developer.nrel.gov/"
urlString.append("&system_capacity=")
urlString.append(capacityStr)

let pvURL = URL(string: urlString)
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: pvURL!) { data, response, error in
    do {

        let _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
        self.jsonString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("JSON String:\(String(describing: self.jsonString))")

        if self.jsonString != nil {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(PVClass.Top.self, from: data!)

            // do some parsing here
            var totalAcKw: Double = 0.0
            let cnt2: Int = (jsonData.Outputs?.ACMonthly.count)!
            for i in 0..<(cnt2-1) {
                totalAcKw = totalAcKw + (jsonData.Outputs?.ACMonthly[i])!
            }
            self.avgMonthlyAcKw = Double(totalAcKw)/Double(cnt2)

            // prints value
            print("updated estimate: ", self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
           completion(self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
        }

    } catch {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}
dataTask.resume()

}
```

calling class:

```
  aPVClass.estimateMonthlyACkW(areaSqFt: 100.0, completion: { (monthlyAckW) -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard case self = self else {
                return
            }

            print("monthlyAckW: ", monthlyAckW)
            self?.estimatedSolarkWh = Int(monthlyAckW * Double((12)/365 * (self?.numDays)!))
            print("estimatedSolarkWh: ", self?.estimatedSolarkWh ?? 0)
            guard let val = self?.estimatedSolarkWh  else { return }
            print("val: ", val)
            self?.estimatedSolarkWhLabel.text = String(val)
            self?.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        }

    })

 }
```

monthlyAckW has the right value after completion handler returns. But the assigned value to self?.estimatedSolarkWh is 0, value never gets transferred to the current class scope, UI update fails, even after DispatchQueue.main.async
How to fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call of `completion` is at the wrong place. Move it into the completion closure of the data task after the print line

```
    // prints value
    print("updated estimate: ", self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
    completion(self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
```

and delete it after resume

`dataTask.resume()`
          <strike>`completion(self.avgMonthlyAcKw)`</strike>
 `}`

Comment: I did that but result is same (actually in my code I had tried that but while posting the code I messed up, so I updated the code as you suggested). But still error is same - monthlyAckW has the right value after completion handler returns. But the assigned value to self?.estimatedSolarkWh is 0. Return value cannot be assigned to calling class scope

Comment: Calling `completion` inside the closure is supposed to work. But this weird `weak self guard` dance in the GCD closure is nonsense. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: I did try without weak self etc and it never worked. There is something missing and I cant figure this out. spent several hours

Comment: Do the `print` lines inside the data task closure display anything?

Comment: All The print lines in called code print. In calling handler only the return value monthlyAckW prints correctly. The var self?.estimatedSolarkWh to which value is assigned does not print the assigned value, instead prints the default init value of the variable estimatedSolarkWh. Here is print output: monthlyAckW:  340.928085327148
estimatedSolarkWh:  0
val:  0

Comment: sorry my mistake, I was getting zero because I was dividing two ints and assigning to Double. It works fine.